# SHChangeNotify() is not working on Windows 8 Start Screen

Tags: winapi

SHChangeNotify() on Windows 7 refreshes icons in desktop and start menu but on Windows 8 it doesn't seem to work on tiles in Start Screen. How can I refresh tile icons in Start Screen on Windows 8 programatically?

My code is similar to the following code:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("Shell32.dll")]
private static extern int SHChangeNotify(int eventId, int flags, IntPtr item1, IntPtr item2);

//SHChangeNotify(0x8000000, 0x1000, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, SHCNF_IDLIST, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Comment: Please show the code and explain what's not working.

Comment: If you change the `0x1000` to `0` does it help?

Comment: Those magic constants are annoying. I can't be bothered to look them up. How do you expect anybody to understand code like that?

Comment: @JonathanPotter I tried 0 instead of 0x1000 but it didn't do the trick. Start Screen remains unchanged.

Comment: I'm not sure that has ever been documented as a way to refresh the Start Screen. And Windows 7 didn't have a Start Screen. For me on Windows 8 it refreshes desktop icons which is all it's meant to do.